# Split a column value to multiple rows based on special character presence and a string match in Postgres

Tags: regex, postgresql, split

i have following table in Postgres11

```
col1            col2                       col3
NCT00065442 APC-Placebo                    apc-placebo
NCT00135226 Placebo                        placebo
NCT00146640 MR Prednisone                  mr prednisone
NCT00146640 Placebo - IR Prednisone        placebo - ir prednisone
```

I would like to split col3 if the string has placebo and has '-' special characters.

The desired output is:

```
col1            col2                       col3
NCT00065442 APC-Placebo                    apc
NCT00065442 APC-Placebo                    placebo
NCT00135226 Placebo                        placebo
NCT00146640 MR Prednisone                  mr prednisone
NCT00146640 Placebo - IR Prednisone        placebo
NCT00146640 Placebo - IR Prednisone        ir prednisone
```

I have tried following queries so far.

```
select *, 
case when col3 ilike '%placebo%' and col3 ~* '-'
        then unnest(string_to_array(col3, '-'))
     else col3
end
from table 
order by col1;
```

I have also tried out replacing unnest(string_to_array) function by below:

```
UNNEST(REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_ARRAY(t.name, '\s*[-]\s*'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Functions like `unnest()` are not allowed inside a `CASE` expression.
You can do it with `UNION ALL`:

```
select col1, col2, trim(unnest(string_to_array(col3, '-'))) col3
from tablename 
where col3 like '%placebo%'
union all
select col1, col2, col3                
from tablename 
where col3 not like '%placebo%'
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6VhBNdAfWBdwb6FftAXmJ3/1).
Results:

```
| col1        | col2                    | col3          |
| ----------- | ----------------------- | ------------- |
| NCT00065442 | APC-Placebo             | apc           |
| NCT00065442 | APC-Placebo             | placebo       |
| NCT00135226 | Placebo                 | placebo       |
| NCT00146640 | Placebo - IR Prednisone | placebo       |
| NCT00146640 | Placebo - IR Prednisone | ir prednisone |
| NCT00146640 | MR Prednisone           | mr prednisone |
```